# Как уменьшить координаты dxf файла?

Tags: libgdx, geojson

Есть большой *DXF (2D)* чертёж размером 100 мб. Я пытаюсь его распарсить в *GeoJSON*. На выходе получаю это:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "SELECT",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "Layer": "Belt - True",
        "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbPolyline",
        "ExtendedEntity": null,
        "Linetype": null,
        "EntityHandle": "4135B",
        "Text": null
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            406377.020367252407596,
            476838.740439196408261
          ],
          [
            403646.96748200408183,
            473806.70955636020517
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Эти координаты** слишком велики. Как я могу их уменьшить?

В дальнейшем, я хочу порезать эту карту на тайлы и отображать их на игровом движке. Извиняюсь если неправильно выразился, буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Если это миллиметры, а нужны метры, то поделить на 1000

Comment: Спасибо, а можно ли как то сжать dxf файл, чтобы сконвертировать его полностью в geojson при помощи онлайн конвертора и не прибегать к конверторам на JS ? Так как у меня он 100 мб mygeodata конвертирует мне только половину файла.

Comment: Ну, можно выкинуть из файла часть данных (ненужные объекты?), тогда он будет меньше места занимать. При желании и наличии лишнего времени можно свой конвертер написать, DXF - это относительно простой текстовый формат.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.

Answer (score 1):

Эти координаты в проекции EPSG:3857(102100 от ESRI и 900913 от Google).

Как я понимаю из вопроса, вы хотите перейти к градусам lat,long. Для этого можно  перепроецировать данные в проекцию EPSG 4326 (WGS84).